# Title and post URL based on custom fields?

Tags: custom-field, permalinks, title

I have custom  fields in my custom post type. They should serve as a title and post slug for URL. Basically, whenever I change the content of the custom fields, the title field should react accordingly. E.g. if the field NAME contains 'John' and the SURNAME 'Smith', the title should transform to 'John Smith'.

The users of the site will be unexperienced so they won't understand the need of putting NAME and SURNAME and a separate title for that - that's why I need it.

I know I can display custom field content instead of a title in my template, but that's not the same. I also need the permalink to be amended accordingly.

So, to recap
My input:
custom field NAME = John
custom field SURNAME = Smith
What should happen:
post title = John Smith
permalink = john-smith (I presume it will process the title extracted from the custom fields as it would normally do)

I hope it's clear now. Thanks indeed for any suggestions.

Comment: I think the title of your quetion and the description are not about the same issue. The permalink structure and the title of the pages are different things. So, what do you want to change? The title of the pages as you describe in the description of the question or the URL structure/permalink as your describe in the title of the question?

Comment: Please, edit your question to match your requeriments. The title and the description of the question and your last comment is all differents things, so we can't know what is your problem and the helop you need.

Comment: Is it understandable now?

Answer (score 1):

I think a good way to do what you want is hook the [`wp_insert_post_data`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_insert_post_data) filter. Here you can change the title and slug of the post before it is saved to database:

```
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'wpse_update_post_title_and_slug' );
function wpse_update_post_title_and_slug( $data ) {

    //You can make some checks here before modify the post data.
    //For example, limit the changes to standard post type
    if( 'post' == $data['post_type'] ) {

        //Add post meta to post title
        $data['post_title'] = $_POST['the-name-field'] . ' ' . $_POST['the-surname-field'];

        //Update the slug of the post for the URL
        $data['post_name'] = sanitize_title( $data['post_title'] );

    }

    return $data;

}
```

Comment: WOW! Didn't know about this powerful function. Thanks for the meaningful example, I'll explore it :)

Comment: Let me know if this answers your question.

Comment: Nevermind all the posts. It's working properly now. It was my mistake. The case is, that it works only when there's something in the title field (doesn't matter what). I understand why it happens, but this title field is to be scrapped from the editor... any ideas how to force it?

I tried using if title is empty, then... but it didn't help.

Comment: I forget to remove `$postarr`. In the code I posted only one argument for `wp_insert_post_data` filter is supported, so the second should be removed or add support to second argument with `add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'wpse_update_post_title_and_slug', '99', 2 );`. I've tested the code and it works correctly. If you want to debug this filter you can use the same function described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878279/how-to-debug-save-post-actions-in-wordpress).

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative, don't set the title at all. Instead, filter it.

Here is `the_title` filter as demonstrated by the codex:

```
function suppress_if_blurb($title, $id) {
    if (in_category('blurb', $id)) {
        return '';
    }
    return $title;
}
add_filter('the_title', 'suppress_if_blurb', 10, 2);
```

If instead we did something like this:

```
function wpse144041_modify_title($title, $id) {
    if ( get_post_type( $id ) == 'yourposttype' ) {
        $first = get_post_meta( $id, 'first', true );
        $last = get_post_meta( $id, 'last', true );
        $title = $first.' '.$last;
    }
    return $title;
}
add_filter('the_title', 'wpse144041_modify_title', 10, 2);
```

Then the title field is now irrelevant, and will show the first and last names as the title on the front end for your post type. Adjust the relevant field and post type names to match

Comment: He needs also the URL slug with the name-surname meta fields. Although you can filter the permalink and combine with custom rewrite rules or query vars to get the correct post, I think is better and much less work having the correct `post_name` (the post URL slug) in the database, thats why I thought in `wp_insert_post_data` filter. This also make manage canonical URLs and redirections with much less effort if needed in the future.

Answer (score -2):

I'm afraid the code above didn't work at all. I modified it like that:

```
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'wpse_update_post_title_and_slug' );
function wpse_update_post_title_and_slug( $data , $postarr ) {

    //You can make some checks here before modify the post data.
    //For example, limit the changes to standard post type
    if( 'people' == $data['post_type'] ) {

        //Add post meta to post title
        $data['post_title'] = $_POST['first_name'] . ' ' . $_POST['last_name'];

        //Update the slug of the post for the URL
        $data['post_name'] = sanitize_title( $data['post_title'] );

    }

    return $data;

}
```

Despite the fact that the particular custom fields are present and have content, neither the title nor the slug changes.

I assumed that both would be amended "by force" upon saving the post? Or maybe  it doesn't work that way?

I also tried to re-code it like this:

```
function wpse_update_post_title_and_slug( $data , $postarr ) {

if( $data['post_type'] == 'people' ) {
// get post data
$id = $postarr['ID'];
$first_name = get_post_meta( $id, 'first_name', true );
$last_name = get_post_meta( $id, 'last_name', true );
// insert the data into the title and the slug
$data['post_title'] = $first_name . ' ' . $last_name;
$data['post_name'] = sanitize_title( $data['post_title'] );
    }

    return $data;

}
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'wpse_update_post_title_and_slug' );
```

But it's all the same. No reaction, no error, no nothing. As it was totally absent from functions.php. It works ordinarily.

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, it is an update to the question, so you should edit the question to add new information and code or it will attrack downvotes.